# Is this crash normal?

Tags: snow-leopard, crash

My Snow Leopard crashed while I was switching from Itunes to the browser.

Basically everything got stuck and a the current song second started to run in loop.

Is that normal ? Can it happen very rarely ? Or should I worry ?

thanks

Comment: Crashes are never normal. They can be more disruptive or less, depending on how often they occur, but they aren't ever normal or acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should worry if it happens to you periodically. If it happened only once, my guess is one of the background process Mac OS X runs from time to time got stuck for a moment.

BTW, when you say "crash", did you have to reboot your computer? Or did it just got stuck for a period of time?

Anyway, if it crashed, the best you could do is send the crash report to Apple when prompted and check the *Usual Suspects*:

- Background processes => **System Preferences** > **Account** > **Login Items** (remove the one you don't need.
- Check how much free space you have left and start removing the files you don't need
- Maybe try to [reindex your hard drive](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409)

Comment: Yeah I needed to reboot the mac. No crash report has been asked, it just froze. ok for all the rest thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not normal.

I started having this problem after I installed "Lion". It happens often, more than several times a day - it freezes, and the only solution is to push the turn off button, turn off the computer, and turn it on again.

I did many researches on this issue, also went to the "Apple" store's "Genius" bar where they reinstalled my operating system which did not help at all. They also checked my hardware and said that everything is okay.

In my opinion, these might be "Lion's" issues, because lots of people have the same problem, and the problem mainly occurred after the "Lion" install. However, it seems that "Apple" does not even try to fix this issue, or even if they do, they are doing it poorly.

Moreover, you might find this useful:

> "Start up Issues/ Slow speed issues/ coloured beach ball:-  (Regular
>   House keeping stuff to clean the computer)
>
> 1. Reset the SMC (Reset System Management Controller)
>
>    For iMacs:- Kindly turn off the computer. 
>      Remove the power chord from the main plug.
>      Press the Power button (at the back of the iMac for 5 seconds). 
>      Reconnect the power cable to the socket and then turn it back on.
>
>    For laptops (mac book, mac book air, mac book pro)
>
>    - Press "left Shift", "left Control", "left Alt" and "Power button' for 5-10 seconds, while the computer is turned off.
> 2. Do a PRAM  Reset
>
> (As soon as you start the computer, press and hold the 4 KEY
>   COMBINATION  till you hear 3 successive starting chymes. The keys are
>   " COMMAND"  "ALT"  "P" and "R")
>
> 1. Do a Safe Boot As soon as you start the computer, press and hold the "Shift key" for 4-5 minutes, till you see a blue screen. (login
>      window)
>
>    - Trash the caches from  Home Folder/ Library/ Caches
>    - Trash  the caches from Mac HD/Lib/Caches
>    - Trash  the start up items from Mac HD/Library/Startup items
>        -Trash the updates from Mac HD/Library/Updates
>    - Delete the Login items from System Pref/Accounts/Login Items
>    - Trash Launch Daemons from Home Folder/Library
>    - Trash Launch Agents from Home Folder/Library
>    - Reset safari, empty caches, delete cookies, 
>        -Restart the Computer"

P.S.: forum to discuss about this issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2768351

I hope this helps.