# Yosemite (> 10.10.x) randomly freezes and crashes on my MacBook Pro 15" Early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, shutdown

I already had a similar problem before and after more than two years of struggling (I had this problem long since the Yosemite) I am still being daily annoyed by the same problem.:

[Is this crash normal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/is-this-crash-normal/47742#47742)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3358689

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2768351?start=1650&tstart=1369#discussion-16646143

However this time it is slightly different. The thing is, it newer "randomly shut downs" while I'm on Windows, doing stuff, playing games, etc. - it only happens on Yosemite, and it is a fresh copy on the new SSD and all that. Therefore, I really don't think it's a hardware problem. There is even nothing in the logs at that time (???)

After I installed the new Yosemite OS with Boot Camp (Windows 8.1 Pro) on my brand new Samsung 840 EVO 1TB SSD, my MacBook Pro randomly froze and after a few minutes - shut itself down.

I even thought it could do something with my USB ports, because of this (only a few keys worked on login when external [USB hub](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0002AFZVM) with [Yeti mic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B002VA464S) plugged in): [Some keyboard keys are not working on login to Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153991/some-keyboard-keys-are-not-working-on-login-to-yosemite) but after some more testing, I can rule that out. It's reproducible with no devices connected over USB.

This problem occurs more frequently when I'm watching videos or working with Photoshop and Illustrator at the same time but sometimes it's totally random (but then, why it's not shutting down when I'm playing games on Windows?) I thought this could be a GPU issue, so I installed [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/), but no luck here.

Could this be an "Automatic graphics switching" issue or is it something else?

Comment: Not much we cam do other than guessing. So could you provide a console log at the time stamp of the event. Normally computers do not shut down if it is a software issue (the might freeze, hand or just shut donwn that app. What it could do that is a severe hardware problem.

Comment: @Buscar웃, I have checked the logs and there are no entries for the specific time of freeze/shutdown.

Comment: The informations you provide aren't very helpful. How often does it freeze/crash? Please install gfxCardStatus and switch it constantly to the Intel graphics chip (you have to do that after every restart twice because of a bug!). Does it still happen? Please install EtreCheck and paste a report @ pastebin/upload it to a dropbox after cleaning it up because of any privacy issues you might have.

Comment: @klanomath, the crash is totally random. I have noticed that it occurs even with the "Automatic graphics switching" turned off.

Comment: Turning "Automatic graphics switching" off doesn't help much detecting the vicious [MBP early 2011](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2768351) bug. Reading 'random freezes' and 'MBP early 2011 15"/17"' my first thought always is 'gfxCardStatus'

Comment: I've cleaned up the **edit** and **edit two** sections. Those are strongly discouraged. If anyone cares to review the edits, they can do so wth the revision tools. Just edit the post so that it's clear, concise and all the information is stored in the most accessible way rather than tacking on new info at the bottom.

Comment: Well, I don't agree. I do not think it is clear to the reader what happened in the long rung. The 'in-question update log' gives sense of depth to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem since a couple of days. Here's what I've done to (apparently) fix it:

Created another Administrator account. Logged onto that account. Removed DropBox, Skype, Viber, Evernote.
Why? Those where the only applications my new account did not run, and my new account never experienced any crashes.

I then got back to my primary account and downloaded the latest version of Skype (7.1) and Viber. I am now running Skype and Viber as before. I had no use for DropBox or Evernote anyway.

I used to have crashes shortly after restarting. I am now on my second hour with a solid machine. I don't know if this will stay so, but at least you can see if it is any help to you.

Comment: What happened in the long run?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone. I recently added a Samsung SSD to my late 2011 17 Macbook Pro running Yosemite and after a few week I had the same issue. Screen freeze, sometime grey screen with lines and then auto re boot. First thing I tried was putting back the old hard drive and that worked so it must be an issue with the SSD. Annoying because with the SSD it was so much faster..

Comment: Yeah, why I don't really like Samsung anything. I've had great luck with Intel for SSDs, though. You should give the 350 Series a try, 240 GB for $100, you can find it at Best Buy.

Comment: I had an HDD before I bought a new SSD and it was freezing nonetheless.

Answer (score -2):

There is not much to go on with what you have given.  It could be an Automatic graphics switching issue.  I've also had a bad SSD present similar freezes.  I would recommend performing diagnostics on the Hard Drive, RAM and anything else you can.  Rule out whether or not you have hardware that is failing.  Then from there, you can begin to troubleshoot the OS.

Comment: I apologize, other stack exchange sites don't allow comments when you are brand new like I am.

Comment: Hello @NewProgrammerJames. If you have had a look at the links I provided in this post, you could notice that I already had the similar issue before.
The SSD I bought is brand new and I have already performed the diagnostics as well. All hardware seems to be working fine. However, this "freeze" never happens while I am on Windows 8 so this must be a Mac OS issue.