# Some keyboard keys are not working on login to Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, login, startup

The problem is that every time I start my MacBook Pro 15" Early 2011, some of the (native) keyboard keys stop working. However, if I click a restart button - it is all fine.

It is definitely not a hardware issue and this did not happen on Mavericks ever.

Comment: I have same issue: 4 keys stopped working on wake from sleep, foolishly restarted Mac in hope it would fix it, now can't login as username contains one of 'broken' keys

Comment: Me too. My 1,2,3 number keys no longer work since updating to Yosemite.On late 2011 13" macbook pro. Have plugged in external keyboard so I can type those numbers.

Comment: look if the assistive devices is turned on in syst pref.

Comment: Are you using FileVault full-disk encryption? If so, it could be an issue with the login screen shown before the OS is booted.

Comment: Yes, I am. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

On the Yosemite login screen, you should see the current Input Method (keyboard) icon in the upper right corner.

If you click on the current input method, a drop-down menu will let you choose which alternate keyboard you can use. That should let you enter it in.

If your keyboard isn't listed, the dropdown menu also has an exhaustive list of other input methods, so you can select one that should let it work.

Note: I haven't tried to change my password to use an alternate keyboard just to see if it works. Maybe for 1000+ rep... ;)

Also, it took about 5 seconds for the input method menu to drop down, so just keep at it until it drops.

Comment: To add on to this, if the problem is that certain physical keys don't seem to be working, you can change keyboard layouts as needed to move around the keys to locations that don't have issues. This probably won't help you if there's an issue with certain characters.

Answer (score -1):

I had this: Numlock had been toggled on.